# Shopify app with proxy extension PUT requests not working

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I have managed to created an app proxy using this guide:
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/display-data-on-an-online-store-with-an-application-proxy-app-extension#handling-proxy-requests

I wanted to update the customer record using a form. On submission of form the below func would be invoked.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#enrollFormID').submit(function() {
    var fname = $(FirstName).val();
    var lname = $(LastName).val();
    var emailID = $(email).val();
    var pass = $(password).val();
     event.preventDefault();
    var data = jQuery(this).serialize();
    console.log(data);
     data = "form_type="+data;
     $.ajax({
      url: '/apps/subpath',
      type: 'PUT',    
       data: data,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
      }
  });
    return true;     
  });
});
```

In the backend app, the below url is getting hit when the form gets submitted, but am not able to retrieve the form data values.

router.put('/test', async (ctx) => {
.....
}

Get request works fine, but with Put request am not able to retrieve the form data from the ajax call.
Can someone help me on this?